# Как убрать слеш / из начала $request_uri

Tags: linux, nginx, alpine-linux

Приветсвую!
Делаю редирект с локального хоста на google.
В начальном запросе в браузере после / идёт поисковый запрос:
http://redirect.localhost/hello

Далее происходит редирект на google.com/search?q=
и проблема в том, что не знаю как добавить к этому адресу (google.com/search?q=) $request_uri без слеша в начале.

Получается вот так:
https://www.google.com/search?q=/hello
а надо так:
https://www.google.com/search?q=hello

Мой код:

```
server {
<------>listen *:80;
<------>server_name redirect.localhost;
<------>return 302 https://google.com/search?q=$request_uri;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную задачу, перерыл весь поиск, никак не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: Использовать другую конструкцию. Nginx - не язык программирования (хотя есть проект openresty). Убрать return и написать `rewrite ^/(.*) https://google.com/search?q=$1 permanent;`

Comment: Могли бы вы пожалуйста пояснить данную запись?

Comment: [rewrite](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) перезаписывает адрес. Тут перезапись по регулярному выражению. Все что в скобках, становится `$1`, и это подстанавливается в новый адрес. `/` находится вне скобок, поэтому не попадает в эту переменную. permanent - 301 редирект. Я не пробовал, но должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, ваш вариант рабочий.